# Removing a nameditem attribute from a NamedNodeMap

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to remove a nameditem from a namednodemap in the code snippet. If I remove it skips over some attributes, may be the map index adjusts when I remove an item.

Any idea as to how to fix this issue?

```
            NamedNodeMap map = thisNode.getAttributes();
            for (int i=0; i < map.getLength(); i++)
            {
                String itemName = map.item(i).getNodeName();
                String itemValue = map.item(i).getNodeValue();
                logger.debug("Attributes [" + itemName + ":" + itemValue + "]");
                if (itemName.equals("xmlns:xsd") || itemName.equals("elementFormDefault") || itemName.equals("targetNamespace"))
                {
                    logger.debug("Keep this attribute[" + itemName + "]");
                }
                else if (itemValue.contains(IDENTIFIER))
                {
                    logger.debug("Keep this attribute [" + itemName + ":" + itemValue + "]");
                }
                else //if (removeThis)
                {                       
                    // remove these attribute name spaces
                    logger.debug("Remove [" + itemName + "]");
                    if (itemName.equalsIgnoreCase(itemName))
                    {
                        //map.removeNamedItem(map.item(i).getNodeName());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to try iterating from end to start like this:

```
for (int i=map.getLength()-1; i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: I am confused as to why this would work. Any explanation to understand this behavior would be helpful.

Comment: If you remove a node with index i from the list, then the following node (originally with index i+1) will become the new node with index i. In your code this node will not get tested (since counter i will be increased by the for-loop). Counting backwards eliminates this. Just debug through an example to understand this.